# Make the width of 1fr + 1fr = 2fr (with grid gap)

Tags: css, css-grid

What's the right way to have my first two columns have the same width total as my third column? if I am splitting them up like so:

```css
.grid {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 2fr;
    grid-gap:2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="small">Col 1</div>
    <div class="small">Col 2</div>
    <div class="large">Col 3</div>
</div>
```

Example here: https://codepen.io/shorty2240/pen/baGYoW

[image: Example]

I was assuming I could make another grid below this one, with the same grid gap, and 1fr 1fr, and it would line up, but obviously it won't.

I would like to avoid nesting the first two items if possible as the actual project is outputting the three items automatically and wrapping around the first two could be problematic.

Comment: `fr` relates to *remaining* space **after** any gaps. You will probably need to nest in this case.

Comment: any other method like flex will be ok with you ? or you want grid system

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think I could solve this with flex, but looking to work out the strengths of grid!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make the grid 4 columns wide and define your `.large` to use up 2 columns.

This is actually in line with the working of columns in popular css frameworks like bootstrap and foundation.

`grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;`

```
.large {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}
```

Or use any of the shorthand syntaxes for both setting 4 columns and grid-column.

Comment: Brilliant, this is the answer I needed. 
Example of why I needed it and how it helped here:
https://codepen.io/shorty2240/pen/rpNpNb

Comment: you can make small `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);`

Comment: There are loads of options with grids. @Paulie_D nicely mentions the span keyword and the repeater. Another nice feature you could use here is `grid-template-areas`. In my answer I've opted for  the (opinionated) easiest to read and understand version.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by @Rene define 4 columns but tell the `.large` divs to span 2 columns and the `.small` only one.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.grid div {
  background: grey;
  height: 75px; /* for demo purposes */
}

.small {
  grid-column: span 1;
}

.large {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="small">Col 1</div>
  <div class="small">Col 2</div>
  <div class="large">Col 3</div>
  <div class="large">Col 4</div>
  <div class="large">Col 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should use `grid-auto-rows: minmax(75px, auto);` in the place of `height ` to have a dynamic size

Comment: The height was just for demo purposes.